# Automatically updating images every 0.5 seconds is not happening

Tags: javascript, html, image

The images that appear when `HTML` opens is this:

[image]

The images that appear when script `refreshIt()` every *0.5 seconds* activated is this:

[image]

**But unfortunately the `HTML` keeps showing the first image, demonstrating that the script is not being activated.

What do I need to do to resolve this issue?**

> **Full Script to test:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .column {
            float: left;
        }
        .left {
            width: 360;
        }
        .middle {
            width: 360;
        }
        .right {
            width: 360;
        }
        .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
        </style>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        function refreshIt() {
            if (!document.images) return;
            document.images['Chart 1'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185109994&selectionId=1485567";
            document.images['Chart 2'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185191931&selectionId=1222344";
            document.images['Chart 3'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185192198&selectionId=47972";
            setTimeout(refreshIt,500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter">
                    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 1</button>
                </form>
                <iframe id="the-frame" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function () {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'), url = document.getElementById('url'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            the_iframe.src = url.value;
                        };
                    }());
                </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart1">
                    <input type="submit" value="Chart 1" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar1" name="ChartBar1" style="width: 286px;"><br>
                </form>
                <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 1">
            </div>
            <div class="column middle">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter2">
                    <input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 2</button>
                </form>
                <iframe id="the-frame2" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function () {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter2'), url = document.getElementById('url2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame2');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            the_iframe.src = url2.value;
                        };
                    }());
                </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Chart 2" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar2" name="ChartBar2" style="width: 286px;"><br>
                </form>
                <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 2">
            </div>
            <div class="column right">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter3">
                    <input type="text" name="url3" id="url3" />
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 3</button>
                </form>
                <iframe id="the-frame3" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function () {
                        "use strict";
                        var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter3'), url = document.getElementById('url3'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame3');
                        url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            the_iframe.src = url3.value;
                        };
                    }());
                </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart3">
                    <input type="submit" value="Chart 3" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar3" name="ChartBar3" style="width: 286px;"><br>
                </form>
                <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval(refreshIt,500)`

Comment: Hi @Kinglish Thank you so much my friend, I had forgotten about that! Please put as an answer so I can validate it as my solution! To resolve, i modify like that: ```<body onLoad=" setTimeout(refreshIt,500)">```

Comment: you didn't call the function `refreshIt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `setInterval()` which will run continuously until it is canceled with `clearInterval()`. Rather than `body onload`, use the `window.addEventListener` method. It helps separate logic from presentation and is best practices.

```
let intervalID
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  intervalID = setInterval(refreshIt, 500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
})

function refreshIt() {
  if (!document.images) return;
  // if want to stop the interval from repeating
  // if (!document.images)  clearInterval(intervalID)
  document.images['Chart 1'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185109994&selectionId=1485567";
  document.images['Chart 2'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185191931&selectionId=1222344";
  document.images['Chart 3'].src = "https://xtsd.betfair.com/LoadRunnerInfoChartAction/?marketId=185192198&selectionId=47972";
}
```